# How to resolve Column Family Id Mismatch Error

Tags: database, scala, cassandra, cql, lagom

```
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Column family ID mismatch (found d58d5af0-110d-11eb-9d7e-01a6151598cb; expected d550a010-110d-11eb-9d7e-01a6151598cb)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.validateCompatibility(CFMetaData.java:941) ~[cassandra-bundle.jar:0.102-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.apply(CFMetaData.java:895) ~[cassandra-bundle.jar:0.102-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.updateTable(Schema.java:687) ~[cassandra-bundle.jar:0.102-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.updateKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:1474) ~[cassandra-bundle.jar:0.102-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.mergeSchema(SchemaKeyspace.java:1430) ~[cassandra-bundle.jar:0.102-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.mergeSchema(SchemaKeyspace.java:1399) ~[cassandra-bundle.jar:0.102-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.mergeSchemaAndAnnounceVersion(SchemaKeyspace.java:1376) ~[cassandra-bundle.jar:0.102-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager$1.runMayThrow(MigrationManager.java:588) ~[cassandra-bundle.jar:0.102-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[cassandra-bundle.jar:0.102-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
```

Everytime when I use sbt cleanrunAll, terminal shows the above error.
And when I use sbt runAll everything working perfect.
So my question is how to resolve above exception when using sbt clean runAll

Comment: is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030661/creating-new-table-with-cqlsh-on-existing-keyspace-column-family-id-mismatch helpful ?

Comment: Not yet I am still looking for exact solution for this.

Comment: Not sure that it is possible to solve, we faced this issue in production and we cannot solve with paid support of Lightbend. One solution that I can suggest do not use auto-create tables, just create it manually.